# export html div into pdf with jspdf

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, jspdf

I have this code, but doesn't work. The console return me this error:

> Cannot read property 'widths' of undefined - jspdf.plugin.from_html.js:169

Someone could help me?

```
<div id="box">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi...
</div>


<button id="pdf_new"> New PDF</button>

<!-- Analytics -->
<script type="text/javascript">

    var doc = new jsPDF();          
    var specialElementHandlers = {
        '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
            return true;
        }
    };

   $('#pdf_new').click(function(){
      var html=$("#box").html();
         doc.fromHTML(html,200,200, {
            'width': 500,
            'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
         });
      doc.save("Test.pdf");
    });


</script>
```

Here you can find the [jspdf.plugin.from_html.js](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/blob/master/jspdf.plugin.from_html.js), problem is at row 720 of this file

Comment: could you provide a working example on http://jsfiddle.net/? It's hard to help you here without knowing what `undefined` should actually be in this case

Comment: Added link to jspdf.plugin.from_html.js file

Comment: same problem JsPDF does not support table colspan also

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found the problem, I didn't include all the main files of jsPDF libraries. Now it works!!

Comment: Please provide a complete answer, let us know which "all" "main files" of JsPDF you added to make it work.?